# problema al ejecutar evento con cierta cantidad de caracteres

Tags: java

Necesito ejecutar un evento en un textfield llamado "txtcodigo" cuando este alcance un largo de 8 caracteres, lo hice de tal manera que cuando el largo sea mayor a 7 entonces esta llame a la funcion "ticket", sin embargo lo esta haciendo cuando se escriben 9 caracteres en el `textfield`:

```
private void txtcodigoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        if (txtcodigo.getText().length()>7) {
            ticket();
        }
}
```

Comment: y si, porque pusiste mayor que 7 y 9 es mayor que 7... o no estoy entendiendo algo...

Comment: Prueba a usar el operador mayor o igual ">= 8"

Comment: si uso >=8 el evento se sigue ejecutando solo cuando escribo 9 caracteres o mas

Comment: @gbianchi asi es, pero 8 tambien es mayor a 7, por lo tanto tambien debiese ejecutar el evento cuando escribo el octavo caracter sin embargo no se ejecuta

Comment: acabo de comprobar que el evento tambien se activa cuando tengo 9 caracteres y borro un caracter del textfield quedando este con 8, pero no cuando paso del septimo al octavo caracter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ejecutar el método cuando la longitud del texto es mayor que 7 esto es correcto, pero recuerda que los espacios pueden agregar una longitud máyor, usa [**trim()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) para eliminar espacios en los extremos del texto:

```
if (txtcodigo.getText().trim().length()>7) { // mayor que 7
    ticket();
}
```

---

Por ejemplo este String tiene una longitud de 8:

```
String s = "Dexen14 ";
int slength = s.length();
```

Si aplicamos el método [**trim()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()), tendría una longitud de 7, que es el valor esperado sin contar el espacio:

```
String s = "Dexen14 ";
int slength = s.trim().length();
```

---

**Actualización**: el usuario escribe "17234752" y desea que al escribir el ultimo digito se active la validación sin embargo esta se activara un carácter después ya que esta llamando el método `KeyTyped()`

debes usar el método [keyReleased()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-) para que al escribir el caracter y liberar la tecla se llamé la validación.

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   if (txtcodigo.getText().trim().length()>7) {
        ticket();
    }
}
```

> [keyReleased()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-) Se invoca cuando se ha liberado una tecla.

Comment: al usar trim el evento tiene el mismo problema. saludos

Comment: y cual es el texto que estas introduciendo. que palabra es?

Comment: estoy escribiendo 17234752, el evento debiese ejecutar cuando escribo el ultimo 2

Comment: estas llamando el metodo tKeyTyped() esto no se llamaría hasta después, debes usar otro método como el keyReleased().

Comment: gracias estimado, ahi estaba el problema, el evento keyreleased era el que correspondia para este caso

Comment: excelente! saludos!

Answer (score 1):

He hecho una prueba con eclipse y me funciona, al llegar a los 8 caracteres. Te dejo el codigo:

Tengo un TextField llamado textField, y un JLabel llamado lblNewLabe.

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(textField.getText().length()>=8){
                lblNewLabel.setText("8 Caracteres !!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Lo he probado y funciona, si sigues teniendo problemas comparte un poco mas de codigo para poder probar tu codigo y buscar el fallo.